# Does work on a detached head branch effect GitHub's contribution graph?

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository, branch

I clone a repository and notice that the files I require only appear
under the original page's **branches** menu, and not under **master**:

> [image]

I `add` and `commit -m` from my machine but the files  don't show up in my newly-formed GitHub repoository under **branches** or **master**. So I run
`git branch -a` and see the 'hidden' files displayed there.  I `git checkout`
and am informed I'm in a detached head state. Next, I `git checkout -b` the
branch with the needed files, then:

```
git push --set-upstream origin
git checkout -
git add
git commit
git push
```

Go back to my GitHub page and the sought after files are now available. We're using this repo for a group project and I want to make sure that our work
on a repo from a headless state will register on each of our GitHub
contribution graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working in a detach head won't impact the contribution graph, since it is a local commit operation (in an headless branch).

Once you have checked out a branch, the same commit will count for the contribution graph, once pushed (not before).

Comment: Thank you for the input @VonC. I will try to decipher what you just said and get back to you tomorrow. Not that you misspoke or weren't clear. i just have to look some of those things up.

Comment: See also from the offcial GitHub documentation: "[What counts as a contribution](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#what-counts-as-a-contribution)"

Comment: I read "what counts as a contribution" . Wanted to say thanks for the answer and the resource. Have a good day @Vonc